# Nginx on CentOS 7 installed successfully getting default page as well but when try to browse application it gives nginx error

Tags: mongodb, nginx, chatbot, pm2

Nginx on CentOS 7 installed successfully getting default page as well but when try to browse application it gives

> nginx error The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
> Please try again later.

When checked the error.log it says

> 2020/10/30 10:25:01 [crit] 355290#0: *1 connect() to 127.0.0.1:7823 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, c$

Adding nginx.conf details:

> server {

> ```
>     listen 443 ssl;
>     listen [::]:443 ssl;
>     server_name xxxxx.in;
>     ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;
>
>     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
>     #root         /var/www/html;
>
>     #index index.php  index.html index.htm;
>     index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
>
>     location / {
>     }
>
>     location /hoh-bot
>     {
>            
>            allow all;
>            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7823;
>            proxy_http_version 1.1;
>            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>            proxy_set_header Host $host;
>            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>        }
>        location /hoh-bot-socket
>        {
>            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7823/socket.io;
>            proxy_http_version 1.1;
>            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
>        }
>        location /hoh2 {
>            return 200 'Testng';
>        }
>        error_page 404 /404.html;
>            location = /40x.html {
>        }
>
>     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
>         location = /50x.html {
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: can you share nginx configuration ?

Comment: Looks like SELinux blocks nginx requests to your upstream, try `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`.